# React state organize state based on days and time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am iterating an array where i am getting day, starttime, and endtime in unorganized manner. I want to organize that data in that format storing in React state. On each iteration i want to insert my data in the state in following manner. If the day is same than insert in that day, if day is new than create new one inside react state. I am using spread operator but still not able to achieve it. In every iteration i have to append the data in the state.

```
[
  "monday": [
               {startTime: STARTTIME, endTime: ENDTIME},
               {startTime: STARTTIME, endTime: ENDTIME},
               {startTime: STARTTIME, endTime: ENDTIME}
            ],
  "tuesday": [
                {startTime: STARTTIME, endTime: ENDTIME}
             ]
]
```

Comment: can you share what you have at the moment - what it the current function your are using to do this? i.e. the one that isnt working for you.  And what does the data look like when it comes into it.

Comment: you should check out the `.reduce()` method of an Array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce